# Will Airflow read from ds or **kwargs in function parameters

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Hi all I have a function

```
def get_campaign_active(ds, **kwargs):
    logging.info('Checking for inactive campaign types..')
    the_db = ds['client']
    db = the_db['misc-server']
    collection = db.campaigntypes
    campaign = list(collection.find({})) 
    for item in campaign:
        if item['active'] == False:
            # storing false 'active' campaigns
            result = "'{}' active status set to False".format(item['text'])
            logging.info("'{}' active status set to False".format(item['text']))
```

mapped to an airflow task

```
get_campaign_active = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_campaign_active',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_campaign_active,
    xcom_push=True,
    op_kwargs={'client': client_production},
    dag=dag)
```

As you can see I pass in the `client_production` variable into op_kwargs with the task. The hope is this variable to be passed in through '**kwargs' parameter in the function when this task is run in airflow.

However for testing, when I try to call the function like so

`get_campaign_active({"client":client_production})`

The client_production variable is found inside the `ds` parameter. I don't have a staging server for airflow to test this out, but could someone tell me if I deploy this function/task to airflow, will it read the client_production variable from `ds` or `kwargs`?

Right now if I try to access the 'client' key in kwargs, kwargs is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
def get_campaign_active(ds, **kwargs):
    logging.info('Checking for inactive campaign types..')
    the_db = kwargs['client']
```

the `ds` (and all other [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) are passed to kwargs as you set `provide_context=True`, you can either use named params like you did or let the ds be passed into kwargs as well)

Since in your code you don't actually use ds nor any other macros you can change your function signature to `get_campaign_active(**kwargs)` and remove `provide_context=True`. Note that from `Airflow>=2.0` the `provide_context=True` is not needed at all.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why in my text editor, the script reads the keyword argument in ds, rather than kwargs? If I understand correctly, pretty much once the DAG is uploaded to airflow, any items in ds are passed to kwargs? I also would remove ds and provide_context=True, but I'm trying to maintain similarity among scripts in my employers codebase.